# Indenting both label and content in description-environment

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

I'm trying to customize `enumitem` so that labels *and* item-contents will be broken into paragraphs with negative (hanging) indent when they get too long for the designated space:

```
     label one                               content one                    |
     label two                               content two content two content|
                                                     two content two content|
                                                     two content two content|
                                                     two                    |
     label three label three label                                          |
           three label three label                                          |
           three                             content three                  |
     label four                              content four                   |
```

The following works for the "content"-part, but  the labels aren't indented and the following label prints on top of the preceding line's.

The latter can be solved manually by adding `\\` after "content three", but as I want to use this in a partly automated workflow, I'd appreciate a solution that doesn't require manual finishing.

Is there a way to achieve this with `enumitem` at all and if not, how could it be done otherwise?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc,enumitem}

\newlist{pardesc}{description}{1}
\setlist[pardesc]{%
nosep,
labelindent=2cm,
labelsep*=1cm,
labelwidth=.5\textwidth-1.5cm, %i.e. same with for both
leftmargin=\labelwidth+5cm, 
style=standard,
align=parleft,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{pardesc}
\item[label one] content one
\item[label two] content two content two content two content two content two content two content two 
\item[label three label three label three label three label three] content three
\item[label four] content four
\end{pardesc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit:

There will frequently be footnotes and pagebreaks in these list, so using  `tabular` instead isn't a feasible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file `enumitem.sty` one def goes like this:

```
\def\enit@align@parleft{%
    \def\enit@align##1{%
         \nobreak
         \strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\raggedright##1}}}}
```

In your preamble you can try removing the `\smash` and put the `\strut` inside the `\parbox`. The `\hangindent` may satisfy your requirements, but you may want some variable length. Change the `\parbox` alignment to `[b]`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\enit@align@parleft{%
    \def\enit@align##1{%
         \nobreak
         {\parbox[b]\labelwidth{\hangindent2.5em\raggedright##1\strut}}}}
\makeatother
```

I don't know if this interferes with any other features, it's only been tested on your example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `tabular` and define new columns to simplify your job.

```
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\bfseries\raggedright\hangindent1.5em\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{>{\raggedright\hangindent1.5em\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\bfseries\raggedright\hangindent1.5em\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{>{\raggedright\hangindent1.5em\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}D{.47\textwidth}E{.5\textwidth}@{}}
label one & content one \\
label two  &  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two \\
label three label three label three label three label three & content three \\
label four & content four
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, but tabular will not be feasible as  there will be frequent pagebreaks and footnotes in these lists.

Comment: @Florian: use `longtabu` then (or equivalent) it provides the benefits of `tabular` while not suffering from footnotes or pagebreaks.

Comment: @HarishKumar you meant "the latter"? b.t.w. I know that it is not supported but I still find it better for its support of `X` columns. Feel free to improve on my answer, anyway, if you have a better version.

Comment: @Federico Oh sorry It should be:  Better to use `longtable` than `longtabu` as the latter is not supported any more. :-) I will delete that comment before David sees it :-)

Answer (score 1):

With `longtabu` and a variation on Harish's answer, you obtain:

**EDIT:** edited to show compatibility with `\pagebreak`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu, longtable}
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\bfseries\raggedright\hangindent1.5em\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{>{\raggedright\hangindent1.5em\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\tabulinesep=^1.5mm_1.5mm

\begin{document}

\noindent
{\centering
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {@{}D{.47\textwidth}  E{.5\textwidth}@{}}
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot

label one & content one \\ 
label two  &  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two \\
label three label three label three label three label three & content three \\
label four & content four\footnotemark  \\ 
label one & content one \\ 
label two  &  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two \\
label three label three label three label three label three & content three \\
label four & content four  \\ 
label one & content one \\ 
label two  &  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two \\
label three label three label three label three label three & content three \\
label four & content four \\ 
label one & content one \\ 
label two  &  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two \\
label three label three label three label three label three & content three \\
label four & content four  \\ 
label one & content one\footnotemark \\ 
label two  &  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two \\
label three label three label three label three label three & content three \\
label four & content four  \\ 
label one & content one \\ 
label two  &  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two \\
label three label three label three label three label three & content three \\
label four & content four  \\ 
label one & content one \\ 
\pagebreak
label two  &  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two  content two content two content two content two content two content two content two \\
label three label three label three label three label three & content three \\
label four & content four  \\ 
\end{longtabu}

\footnotetext[1]{text one}
\footnotetext[2]{text two}

\end{document}
```

That is a 3-page table with footnotes and a `\pagebreak`